Magento 2.4.6 - category canonical tag after update category url key
i use the canonical links for categories and products,
now have i a problem.
After update url key for some category the rel attribute=canonical in source code remained old.
How can i change it?


I'm not sure this is your issue but you should also check directly in database with the url_path attribute of your category...i already faced issue where this attribute is not properly updated and was leading to this kind of issue.

The problem exists, I installed now a completely clean Magento 2.4.6-p6, without extern modules, without sample data - The Problem exists.
I don't know which version the problem started with, for Example with Magento 2.4.1 have i no Problem.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/29665275?key=dccd51181d6845664c5e553b359f0758

I tested all versions, the problem exists only in 2.4.6 in all subversions,
in earlier versions, f.ex. from 2.4.1 to 2.4.5 - in all subversions -  and in 2.4.7 no problem.
